# Merging two Mono and getting a Flux. Then extracting a Mono from that Flux

Tags: mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux, reactor

I have **two** `Mono<T>` that i have got from **two different sources** let us say `KAFKA`.

My intention is to merge **both these** `Mono` into a `Flux<T>`. **1**

Then use `public final Mono<T> reduce(BiFunction<T,T,T> aggregator)` method in `Flux` to create a final `Mono` out of it (as the response time of above two `Mono` may vary). **2**

**approach:**

There are many methods such as `contact`, `zip`, `zipWith` to use on `Flux`. How do i arrive at a correct method to use  (Two `Mono` to `Flux` conversion i.e, **1**).

And is this `REDUCE`  approach really correct or is there anything else could be done  to improvise it (**2**) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a `Flux` to do this, then you'd likely want to use `merge()`, similar to:

```
Flux.merge(mono1(), mono2()).reduce((obj1, obj2) -> foo(obj1, obj2));
```

...where `foo()` fulfils the functionality of the `reduce` method in the question, combining both objects emitted into a single value. You wouldn't want to use `concat()` unless you want to subscribe to each `Mono` one at a time, waiting for each to complete, rather than all together - and the `Flux.zipXXX` series of operators would be used for zipping separate fluxes together, so you wouldn't want that.

However, I don't think you quite have the correct approach here for two values - if you want to put two `Mono` publishers into a `Flux` and then immediately reduce them back to a `Mono`, then it doesn't make much sense to use a `Flux` at all, since you have to wait for both the publishers to complete before emitting anything, and then you're just emitting a single value.

Instead, I'd recommend using [this variant of `Mono.zip()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-java.util.function.BiFunction-), which allows you to do everything you need in one go, something like:

```
Mono.zip(mono1(), mono2(), (obj1, obj2) -> foo(obj1, obj2));
```